# Is the ~ character special at the start of a filename?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

If I create a file named `~abc.tmp` and then try to use Command Prompt's character completion feature (usually TAB), it doesn't behave the same way as normal characters:

- If I type `~` and press TAB, it "completes" the file name incorrectly to `~"~abc.tmp"`.
- If I type `~a` and press TAB, it fails to complete the file name.

Is there something special about the `~` character that I'm not aware of?

(I know that the 8.3 variants of long file names contain a `~` at the end, but I'm talking about `~` at the start.)

Comment: I did the same as you and got the similar results, but that I noticed that repeated `Tab` presses steps through all the files in the directory, and `~a` `Tab` found all files beginning with `a`. In all cases the typed `~` was retained, so it never yielded a valid file name. All a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

The tilde prefix on a temporary item is commonly created by Microsoft applications.

> Windows Desktop applications, such as Write, and multiple document interface (MDI) applications, such as Excel, create temporary files to handle necessary user editing.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/92635/windows-temporary-files

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question that was asked. The question was asking about a specific behaviour, not if random programs use it to denote temporary files.

Comment: What Mokubai said is correct - this does not answer my question - but it is quite interesting nevertheless; therefore I'll upvote it but I won't mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Apologies - I did misread the question.

Comment: Just playing around with this and looks like a few other special characters (comma, backtick, semi-colon) have a similar effect - leaving the special character but cycle through files. A backslash will begin autocompleting for C:\